# MonoTouch Linked Library Compile Issue After Upgrading

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, linker-errors

I upgraded yesteday to the newest MonoTouch / MonoDevelop build and now my application is throwing the following error when compiling:

```
error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc: "-lz" "-lxml2"
```

I am using the following on my build because a linked library I am using requires libz.dylib.
-gcc_flags "-lz -lxml2"

My current enviroment is:

```
MonoDevelop 3.0.5
Installation UUID: 5022d668-f236-4223-a074-6c050535bd3f
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
    GTK 2.24.10
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 210090011
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.5.2 (1847)
     Build 4G2008a
Monotouch: 6.0.7
Mono for Android: Not Installed

Build information:
    Release ID: 30005000
    Git revision: e159cf083bd327933166819d94245298898d6e3d
    Build date: 2012-10-24 16:43:06+0000
    Xamarin addins: eea2ed91ae8dd242b281d5ec8f6c2fbc63b4cd3d
Operating System:
    Mac OS X 10.7.5
    Darwin My-Mac-mini-2.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2
        Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012
        root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Originally nothing changed besides a update of MonoTouch / MonoDevelop to newest stable build.  On update I had to re-license MonoTouch so I did that and all installed fine.  Than on build it fails with that.  I than updated Xcode hoping that solved it, reason I am on the newest Xcode, and it did not.

Unrelated, this is not my only issue I am having since updating.  On another project my views are showing up at a 90 degree rotation, however do not worry about that. Just mentioning it in case it may help solve the issue as maybe something went wrong with my upgrade?

---

Addition Build Error Info:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -arch i386  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -c /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/main.i386.m -o /Users/Company/Projects/App/4-PDF2/App.Kiosk/obj/Debug/mtouch-cache/main..i386.cache.xT4QTbvqc0Zrv4eGTYvIJcXuuvo=.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++  -Wl,-no_pie -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk  /Users/Company/Projects/App/4-PDF2/App.Kiosk/obj/Debug/mtouch-cache/main..i386.cache.xT4QTbvqc0Zrv4eGTYvIJcXuuvo=.o -o /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/AppKiosk -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Accounts -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion -framework GameKit -framework GLKit -framework iAd -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenGLES -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework Twitter -framework UIKit -framework PassKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -framework ExternalAccessory -framework AdSupport -framework QuickLook -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -liconv -lmonosgen-2.0 -lmonotouch-sgen -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -lmono-profiler-log -u _mono_profiler_startup_log -u _catch_exception_raise  -force_load /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/libPSPDF-ios5.1.a -force_load /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/libBARCODE-iphoneos.a "-lz" "-lxml2"
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++  -Wl,-no_pie -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk  /Users/Company/Projects/App/4-PDF2/App.Kiosk/obj/Debug/mtouch-cache/main..i386.cache.xT4QTbvqc0Zrv4eGTYvIJcXuuvo=.o -o /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/AppKiosk -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Accounts -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion -framework GameKit -framework GLKit -framework iAd -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenGLES -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework Twitter -framework UIKit -framework Paerror MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc: "-lz" "-lxml2"
ssKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -framework ExternalAccessory -framework AdSupport -framework QuickLook -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -liconv -lmonosgen-2.0 -lmonotouch-sgen -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -lmono-profiler-log -u _mono_profiler_startup_log -u _catch_exception_raise  -force_load /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/libPSPDF-ios5.1.a -force_load /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/libBARCODE-iphoneos.a "-lz" "-lxml2"
ld: file not found: /var/folders/ln/yb817btn4_s7b52rhfk80cmm0000gn/T/tmp478d0592.tmp/libBARCODE-iphoneos.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: **MonoTouch: 2.10.9 (tarball)** <- that sounds like a Mono, not a MonoTouch version. Please use MonoDevelop (about Menu) to copy/paste the version information. That's the best way to avoid errors and provide all the required data to diagnose issues.

Comment: Mono version is 6.0.7. I updated it in my post.  It was 6.0.6 but trying the BETA version in hopes that solves my issues, which it did not.

Comment: You're confusing Mono and MonoTouch. Please provide the exact (copy/pasted) information from MonoDevelop and the (copy/pasted unedited) build log.

Comment: No I am not, i am just trying to debug as I am editing my post so typoing.  MonoTouch version is 6.0.7.  The version when I first posted this was 6.0.6 and I just updated it to the beta version of 6.0.7 to try that.  As my post said, it was the newest stable built, which is 6.0.6. None the less I will add the mono info above shortly

Comment: Look at your (3 up) comment `Mono version is 6.0.7.` ;-)

Comment: I know, as I said I am typoing because I am trying to debug this on my own while I also am posting edits to help people on here solve the issue. I apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

> error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc: "-lz" "-lxml2"

This means the native linker failed. The most common (but not the only) reason is when people change their options. Which is why the **first** thing to do is to check your user flags (they both look fine).

The next step is to see why the native linker failed. To do so you need to review your **Build Output** (that you can see inside MonoDevelop's **Error List** pad).

Check for any warnings (either on the log or inside MD error list pad). There's likely a bit of extra information in there.

Also what version of Xcode were you using previously ? (i.e. before your update)

Xcode 4.5 will only work for ARMv7 (and ARMv7s) so if you used Xcode 4.4 (or earlier before) it's possible you're trying to use some 3rd party bindings that are only available for ARMv6. That's something that the native linker won't like (and you should see warnings in your build log).

Comment: I have not changed anything, so changes to my build options can't be the reason. I simply updated the software since the update popup came up.   

I attached the additional build data in my post as an edit above, however this error did come from the Build Output and at least to me, the addition info is not all that helpful.

As for what xcode, cannot remember.  It was updated only about 2 months ago so if 4.5 has been out a while it would have been that.

Comment: I posted the additional errors and as you can see the route of the problem still comes down to the original [error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc: "-lz" "-lxml2].  I am looking into the ARM issue now

Comment: From the build log it seems you're using the simulator. You need to check that `libBARCODE-iphoneos.a` (reported as missing) is available for the i386 architecture. If not then it will report an error (since there's nothing to link with). Older MT did not report an error (and let this be a runtime issue) and newer (unreleased) versions will also do the same. For the moment do not link the wrong architectures in your projects.

Comment: Per you post, I am building a multi-platform .A file so I first build a version for the simulator using i386 and than one for the iPhone using ARM7.  After that I build a final one that packages the two into a single build.   Are you saying that as of XCode 4.5, iPhone simulator no longer needs i386? It now supports ARMv7? Or you just are stating to not worry about ARMv6 (which I am not)

Comment: pou: My .a is a package of both so I can run this in the simulator and on the device at the same time.  I don't exactly want to keep switching which .A is attached depending on where I am deploying to.  This is done in XCode using the [lipo - create "sim.a" "iphone.a" - output "combined.a"] shell script of a 3rd target.  Worked perfect as of before my upgrade.

Comment: Not sure. Why is the linker looking for `libBARCODE-iphoneos.a` ? is that the name of your **fat** (i386+ARMv7) static library ? You better open a bug report and attach your binding .dll (make it private if needed) so we can take a look at it (and see if it's related to the MT or Xcode update).

Comment: There is almost no possible way it is related to the XCode update. I only updated xCode because of this so it existed before hand. "libPSPDF-ios5.1.a" is the name of the library I am adding to my Bindings DLL project.  The file you listed is actually the iphoneos version of the A that is in my FAT static library, so not sure why it's even being listed there.

Comment: I will further look into why it is failing on that. It has to do for sure with the way it is passing my arguments to that .A file it appears so hopefully that helps. If not I will open a ticket, however I kind of need this fixed now so I will do all I can to solve it first.  It's not exactly a good situation when you go to compile something, simply update your IDE and that breaks everything.  A 2nd project that is landscape has all of my views showing at a 90 degree angle after the same upgrade =/